# 403 Forbidden not redirected to ASP MVC 5 - Razor View custom <httperror> for IIS8

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5, iis-8, http-error, custom-errors

I try to redirect users that have no autorization for different pages from my app to a custom  error page: `CustomErr/Forbidden_403` - controller(that have a razorview). I've also configured `<customErrors>` in my `Web.config` but I need `<httpErrors>` too because for some reason, when I publish to the server, this 403 error is not overriden(more it shows 404 not found error instead of 403).

I need a relative path to the View: `path="~/CustomErr/Forbidden_403"` because my server have multiple apps and each app have it's own folder.

What I've seen so far:

1. If I add `subStatusCode` with or without relative path("~") : `<error statusCode="403" subStatusCode="14" path="~/CustomErr/Forbidden_403" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />` then the browser return a HTTP 403 error page ("The website declined to show this webpage")
2. If I remove `subStatusCode`: `<error statusCode="403" path="~/CustomErr/Forbidden_403" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />` then the browser shows a HTTP 404 error("The webpage cannot be found")
3. If I remove `subStatusCode` and relative path("~"): `<error statusCode="403" path="/CustomErr/Forbidden_403" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />`then the browser return a HTTP 403 error page ("The website declined to show this webpage")
4. I also have a `PageNotFound_404` Controller and error defined in `web.config` which is working fine if I write down an incorrect URL in browser.
5. The custom error is not showing only for 403 Forbidden => I user return `new HttpStatusCodeCresult(HttpStatusCOde.Forbidden)` for throwing this 403 code to server.

`Web.config`

```
 <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
          <remove statusCode="403" />
          <remove statusCode="404" />
          <error statusCode="403" path="~/CustomErr/Forbidden_403" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
          <error statusCode="404" path="~/CustomErr/NotFound_404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
  </httpErrors>
```

Do I need to configure it from IIS?

Answer (score 1):

What I eventually did was to override paths from `Web.config` in `Web.Release.config`

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
          <remove statusCode="403" />
          <remove statusCode="404" />
          <error statusCode="403" path="/myAppFolder/CustomErr/Forbidden_403" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
          <error statusCode="404" path="/myAppFolder/CustomErr/NotFound_404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
  </httpErrors>
```

Also all js files with ajax that have url to controllers, I've modified urls from `url:"/Controller/Action"` to `url:"Controller/Action"` - they will automatically figure relative path.

Comment: Is your problem solved? If it is solved, please accept answer, which can help more people get same problem.

Comment: @samwu  yes it’s solved but I can’t accept my own answer, right now.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove subStatusCode and relative path("~"), and shouldn't the end of the value of your `path` be html or htm?  below code works on my side.

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
  <remove statusCode="404"/>
  <error statusCode="404" path="/Errors/404.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
</httpErrors>
```

Comment: I need razor view for fallback, not .html - I figure what the problem was, I'll post an answer with the fix later